# Oracle 10g declare number field > 2000

Tags: oracle10g

Hy folks, 
I need to declare a number field on a oracle database that needs to start on 2000.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean that it must be greater than 2000 or "start on 2000", but anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  mynumbercolumn NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT min2000 CHECK (mynumbercolumn >= 2000)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I sought.

Answer (score 1):

You want to declare a sequence that starts at 2000?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE yoursequencename
    MINVALUE 2000
    START WITH 2000
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Skeleton syntax is

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
    MINVALUE value
    MAXVALUE value
    START WITH value
    INCREMENT BY value
    CACHE value;
```

Comment: of course, this doesn't stop me inserting a value less than 2000... :)

Comment: I wondered whether there weren't already a couple thousand manually inserted rows in that table. I decided not to ask.